# Code implementation to communicate with other microservices with openshift

Tags: spring-boot, openshift

Hy,

I am a total newbie in openShift and the first doubt I have is how to implement the communication between my microservices in a spring boot application. With Netflix, one common configuration is like the next:

```
@FeignClient("http://notification-service")
public interface NotificationVersionResource {  
    @RequestMapping(value = "/version", method = GET)
    String version();
}
```

Spring boot will create the implementation at runtime finding an implementation of ribbon in a jar file.

1. How does it work with openshift?
2. Do I have to change something in my code?
3. Do I need to add some jar to my maven project?

Thanks

Comment: which version of openshift are you using?  v2 or v3 ?

Comment: I think we will use openshift 3. Anyway, where can I find this documentation? Thanks

Comment: i have an example here that shows deploying java app and connecting to mysql https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-geXg6AOTo4&list=PLS92o8LZHcPSGHxlK65EMMuaL4OUM2ded&index=5        official  docs:  docs.openshift.org